# Satellite doesnt send request to report suite in Adobe Analytics only for ios

Tags: ios, adobe-analytics, satellite, adobe-dtm

I have hybrid app with native part (Adobe Mobile Library) and web app (Satellite). All works fine on our uat apps. Hits from native part and web part are send to uat report suite. Problem occurs only for iOS prod app. I checked 100 times config adbmobile json for ios. Maybe one of you has similar problem and knows solution? Of corse on prod enviroment we have hits from nativepart, problem occurs after web app entrance.

Comment: Do you see _any_ requests in the prod app? Perhaps the requests happen but are being routed to the uat report suite?

Comment: Yes I see reauests from native part of my application